# Javascript animation taking incorrect amount of time to reach desired location

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, math

I've spent an hour or two trying to uncover the problem with my math but cant seem to find it. I create a visual that has a certain height based off of how long the note was pressed. It will fall down and I want to play the audio once it hits the key. The key is 25% of the key_wrapper. (measurements in attached image)

I make the duration 3 seconds for the key to travel from 0 top to key_wrapper top (so that top of div is 0 from bottom), then I get this rate of speed and multiply it to the visual height as the animation starts from -visual_height. This should keep the 3 second timing from -visual_height to 0 top. Then I play the sound at 75% of 3 seconds as it should be 3 seconds to go from top 0 to top key_wrapper height, which means if we consider the bottom of the visual is at 0 top at the start, it should be at the top of the key (25% wrapper height) at 75% of the 3 second rate defined in the duration.

[image: Piano with measurements]

```
// visual creation
return ({...prev_state,
          [pb_counter.current]: (
          <div key={`${pb_counter.current}`} ref={ref => playback_visual_refs.current[pb_counter.current] = ref} className='pb-visualizer-instance'
          style={{height: `${(timestamps[1] - timestamps[0]) * 0.3}px`}}></div>
          )
        })

useEffect(() => {
    if (playback_visuals[pb_counter.current] && curr_pb_anim.current[1]) {
      const computed_style = window.getComputedStyle(playback_visual_refs.current[pb_counter.current])
      const height = parseFloat(computed_style.getPropertyValue('height'))
      const duration = 3000 + ((3000 / key_wrapper.current.clientHeight) * height)
     

      // Timer just sets a timeout
      const f_timeout_id = new Timer(() => {
        audio.current.play()
       // ((3000 / key_wrapper.current.clientHeight) * 7.5) for 7.5 pixel line on top of keys
      }, (3000 * .75) + ((3000 / key_wrapper.current.clientHeight) * 7.5))

      
      curr_pb_anim.current[0].push(attribute_animation(playback_visual_refs.current[pb_counter.current], 'top', 
      `-${height}px`,
       `${(key_wrapper.current.clientHeight)}px`, duration))
        curr_pb_anim.current[1] = false
    }
    
  }, [playback_visuals])

// animation function
export const attribute_animation = (object, attribute, start, end, duration, easing) => {
    return object.animate(
        [{[attribute]: start}, { [attribute]: end}],
        {duration: duration, fill: 'forwards', easing: easing}
    )
}
```

Comment: Why implement your own animation code? Why not do this with CSS transitions or JQuery animate? Even if you can't get precisely the animation you want through these, what you're doing here seems like a lot of pain for not much gain.

Comment: @ControlAltDel this is a playback so the user needs to be able to pause and unpause the animations. I considered doing it through CSS but couldnt get it working